# GET request with different mongo find results on same page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like my website to have a search bar in the top section that returns a single document (ink) from a mongo database. On the same page, I would like to be able to access all documents from the same database.

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to do this on one page, since I can only send one result to URL.

Is there some way to send all documents to the page, then do a search with AJAX on the client side? I'm new to coding, and wondering if I'm going about this wrong.

I appreciate any help. Here is part of my code that sends the results I want, but to different pages.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){

// FIND ONE INK FROM DB
  var noMatch = null;
  if(req.query.search) {    
    Ink.find({ink: req.query.search}, function(err, foundInk){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        if(foundInk.length < 1) {
          noMatch = "No match, please try again.";
      }
        res.render('new-index', {ink: foundInk, locationArray: locationArray, noMatch: noMatch })
      }
    });
  } else {

    // FIND ALL INKS FROM DB
    Ink.find({}, function(err, allInks){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.render("index", {ink: allInks, locationArray: locationArray, noMatch: noMatch });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use separated endpoints for each request. For the full access request, you can render the page, calling `res.render`, and for the search request, you can return a json calling `res.json`. Something like this:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  // FIND ALL INKS FROM DB
  Ink.find({}, function(err, allInks){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("index", {ink: allInks, locationArray: locationArray, noMatch: noMatch })
    }
  });
})

app.get("/search", function(req, res) {
  // FIND ONE INK FROM DB
  var noMatch = null;
  Ink.findOne({ink: req.query.search}, function(err, foundInk){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else 
      if(!foundInk) {
        noMatch = "No match, please try again.";
      }

      res.json({ink: foundInk, locationArray: locationArray, noMatch: noMatch })
    }
  });
});
```

Note the call to `Ink.findOne` in the `/search` handler, which will return only one document.

This way you can make and AJAX request to /search, and parse the json returned from the server.

I've created a sample repository with the exact same issue [here](https://github.com/renatovassao/ajaxsearch)

Comment: I made an AJAX request in my main.js by clicking search button in EJS file:
`$(".search-button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({  
    url: '/search',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});`
but it's logging null. If I do a get request straight from the form to /search, it returns my search result object. I know you said parse the json, but I'm not sure where to do that, or if that's why it's returning null from the AJAX. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Try adding an error function to your AJAX call to print the error and send the result here. Also, in your main.js, check how are the parameters coming from the AJAX request and the browser request, to see if we are missing something.

Comment: I added the error function, but I'm not getting an error back. To check how the parameters are coming from AJAX and browser I tried this, to make sure the query was being sent to the AJAX and am getting an alert now with the query: `$(".search-button").click(function(){
  *query = $('#autocompleteInks').val()*
  $.ajax({  
    url: '/search' + '?search=' + query,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data.ink.ink);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
  });
});` but I can't use <%=ink.ink %> or in EJS

Comment: Ok, so if the success function is executing it means that your server is returning a response with status 2xx. Try checking the request and response on the server side. Investigate their properties like req.query and the foundInk object you are returning. Also, try making the request to your server via another client, such as cURL or postman, to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: Ok, in postman I can do a GET to (http://localhost:3000/search?search=133) (or whatever number at the end) and get an object of the query returned, so there must be something wrong with my AJAX? If I do `url: '/search' + '?search=' + query,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $('.result').html(data.ink.ink);
      alert(data);
    },` 133 will briefly show in my EJS and disappear, but the alert is "[object Object]"

Comment: Can you post your ejs please?

Comment: <div class="row">
        <form id="query">
            <div class="row form-group">
                <input id="autocompleteInks" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search..." class="searchbox">
                <input type="submit" value=">" class="btn-sm btn-primary search-button">
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="result">
                <p><%= ink.ink %></p>
                <p><%= ink.location %></p>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: I think the problem is that when your are calling `$('.result').html(data.ink.ink)`, you are overwritting `<p><%= ink.ink %></p> <p><%= ink.location %>`, so when you make a search you delete the data that you rendered with the locals from the first handler. But your AJAX call is working, try switching that `alert(data)` to `console.log(data)` to see what data you are retrieving.

Comment: I want to thank you again for your help on this. I appreciate it so much. console.log(data) doesn't return anything. Is there another way I should be passing data from the main.js AJAX to the ejs?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, been in a rush these last days. I've created a sample repository with the exact same issue [here](https://github.com/renatovassao/ajaxsearch). Check if that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you make an endpoint like this.

```
( id parameter is optional here...thats why the '?' )   
www.example.com/api/inks/:id?


// return all the inks
www.example.com/api/inks

// return a specific ink with id=2
www.example.com/api/inks/2
```

So now you can render all the links via `/inks` and search a particular ink by using the endpoint `/ink/:id?`

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you for your help. Right now my endpoint for all inks is `www.example.com/` and when I search, the endpoint is `www.example.com/?search=123`. I'm confused on the part where I'm rendering the page and sending {ink: foundInk} or {ink: allInks}. Is there a way to use those as variable and send both with the endpoint `www.example.com/2`? Sorry if I'm not making sense.

Comment: Yeaah...I am not getting what you're trying to say. Use what as a variable and send what and why to the endpoint /2 ?

Comment: I was using /2 from your example as the endpoint. And I was wondering if there was a way to use the result from the search as a variable, to use on the client side. Basically, I don't understand how (at any endpoint), there can be results from `Ink.find({})` *and* `Ink.find({ink: req.query.search})`. Would it help to show my ejs file?